# How to delete node from RB-tree

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees, red-black-trees

I need to implement my own red-black tree and I am stuck with deletion. I have found this [book (Introduction to Algorithms)](https://cdn.manesht.ir/19908___Introduction%20to%20Algorithms.pdf) (p.222) and in the following code I can't understand this marked line.
[image: RB-Delete]

Firstly, why do I need to do that if `x.p` is already pointed at `y`, because it is in particular `y.right.p` (`== y`).
Secondly, what if `x` is `NIL` and has no any fields then?
Please, can you explain me this?